# Java would not Iterate Treemap using Entry inside try block

Tags: java, loops, hashmap, treemap

**Solution: Restarting my PC fixed the problem. Apparently Eclipse was getting confused with both:**

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
```

Imports are:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import dms.model.DATA_FOR_ALL;
import dms.model.ReportProblemFile;
import dms.model.ReportUserActions;
import dms.model.SendEmail;
import dms.view.MainFrameWithListeners;
```

My Map is:

```
private TreeMap<Integer,StoreProblem> local_copy_of_store_problems_map = new TreeMap<Integer,StoreProblem>();
```

**I want to understand why my code will iterate through this: (size is 79)**

```
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, StoreProblem> entry : this.local_copy_of_store_problems_map.entrySet()) 
    {
         System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + ". Value: " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

**But NOT this:(size is 79)**

```
        for(Entry<Integer, StoreProblem> queue : this.local_copy_of_store_problems_map.entrySet()){
               System.out.println("Key: " + queue.getKey() + ". Value: " + queue.getValue());
     }
```

**In fact, it only printed out key 0...**

**What is the difference here? :**

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, StoreProblem> entry : 

for(Entry<Integer, StoreProblem> queue :
```

Comment: There is absolutely no difference. If that code compiles, `Entry` and `Map.Entry` are referring to the same type.

Comment: I think what @SotiriosDelimanolis is saying is that there is something outside of the code snippets you've provided that is causing the behavior you're seeing. Your edit really doesn't add any value to your question.

Comment: No, if I swap out the Map.entry with entry it will not iterate past index 0

Comment: Post a complete and reproducible example. There is nothing obvious we can do with the code you've provided.

Comment: I can tell you, however, that it has nothing to do with the try-catch.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot do that. I commented out everything and can still produce the problem with JUST the snippet I've provided. Nothing else is in the class.

Comment: OK so there is no difference with Map.entry and Entry?

Comment: Show us your import statements.

Comment: Do you have your own class called Entry?

Comment: No. Check your imports. You should find that the second example has an import of java.util.Map.Entry.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If he did, this would not compile. Even if it subclassed Map.Entry, this would fail.

Comment: It was import java.util.Map.Entry; that caused the problems!!!!  @AndySenn please post import as answer and I will mark!

Comment: The imports were fighting each other

Comment: @Petro Awesome. Glad to hear that things are working for you now. :)

Comment: Both `Map.Entry` and `Entry` should be referring to the same thing with the `import` statements you've shown.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes the *Should*, not guareteed I guess

Comment: @Petro Can you please update your post with what you mean by "The imports were fighting each other". I'm still intrigued as to how this actually compiled. Your explanation would help others that run into this issue and stumble upon this post, but we still need to know what the "issue" is...

Comment: Thanks everyone, I really appriciate it! Was pulling my hair out! LOL

Comment: No, that doesn't make any sense. The specification is very well defined. Nothing is _not guaranteed_.

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Map.Entry<Integer,StoreProblem> to Entry

Comment: Don't post things out of context. Edit your question, explain what that is (a compilation error) and where it happened, under which conditions, explicitly.

Comment: That still doesn't make any sense though. It wouldn't compile if Map.Entry and Entry were different classes. Importing both would not cause this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution: Restarting my PC fixed the problem. Apparently Eclipse was getting confused with both:**

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
```

Comment: This should be closed as unreproducible.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Agreed - The issue, as it is described, is nonsensical.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that he said it was working, accepted an answer, then discovered that restarting his computer (effectively clearing out the caches in Eclipse) was the solution to his problem. This flow is illogical...

Comment: Well it was being spotty the PC hadn't booted in weeks give me a break will ya?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are importing Entry from java.util.Map properly:

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;
```

Comment: OP has shown that they already have that import statement.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yeah, sorry. He edited those into the post shortly before I posted my answer. When he said this fixed it, I assumed the issue really did reside in his imports. Oye...